# Want to use cos^-1 in Swift

Tags: swift, math, vector, trigonometry

I need help with my Swift code. I don't know how to use cos^-1. Would be great if anyone could show me a way.

```
 let cosinus = cos((.pi * cosinusValue / 180))
```

Comment: `acos()` is the function for the inverse cosine.

Comment: Isn't that just the same as `1/(cos(...))`?

Comment: @VaughanHilts [`cos⁻¹` is commonly used in English-speaking countries for `arccos`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Notation)

Comment: @VaughanHilts depends on the notation `^-1` can mean both power and inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acos()` and other mathematical functions from the BSD library can be used directly from Swift. Example:

```
import Darwin // or Foundation

let x = 0.0
let angle = acos(x)

print(angle) // 1.5707963267948966 (radians)
print(angle * 180.0 / .pi) // 90.0 (degrees)
```

In a future version of Swift these functions are also available as static functions on the floating point types, compare [SE-0246 Generic Math(s) Functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0246-mathable.md)

```
let x = 0.0
let angle = Double.acos(x)

print(angle) // 1.5707963267948966 (radians)
print(angle * 180.0 / .pi) // 90.0 (degrees)
```